# Convert MySQL *.sql scripts(statements) to MS SQL SERVER *.sql script(statements)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How to convert MySQL *.sql scripts(statements) to MS SQL SERVER *.sql script(statements)?

For example, here is the MySQL sql statements:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `qs_ad_category`;
CREATE TABLE `qs_ad_category` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `alias` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `categoryname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `admin_set` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `qs_admin`;
CREATE TABLE `qs_admin` (
  `admin_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `admin_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `pwd` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `pwd_hash` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `purview` TEXT  NOT NULL,
  `rank` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `add_time` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `last_login_time` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `last_login_ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`admin_id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM ;
```

Sure I cannot execute this script in MS SQL SERVER2012, because some syntax is different. Is there any quick way to convert? Or the best way to do it is still manually rewrite a MS SQL version?

Comment: Like  that? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28764

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use master;
go
if db_id('name_of_the_database')is not null
begin
    drop database name_of_the_database;
end

go
create database name_of_the_database;
go
use name_of_the_database;
go


if object_id ('qs_ad_category')is not null
begin 
    drop table qs_ad_category;
end

create table qs_ad_category
(
id smallint check (id between 1 and 5) NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) primary key,
alias varchar(100) NOT NULL,
type_id int check (type_id between 1 and 10) NOT NULL,
categoryname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
admin_set tinyint  check(admin_set between 1 and 3) NOT NULL default '0'
);
go
```